# Finding nearest point in SpatiaLite without GEOS

Tags: sql, nearest-neighbor, spatialite

I want to find the nearest point having latitude and longitude stored as Point in SpatiaLite. I read [this](http://northredoubt.com/n/2012/01/27/of-file-sizes-and-nearest-neighbors/) and it has this example:

```
SELECT feature_name, feature_class, 
     ST_Distance(Geometry, MakePoint(-70.250, 43.802)) AS Distance FROM XYGNIS 
WHERE distance &lt; 0.1 AND ROWID IN 
( SELECT ROWID FROM SpatialIndex 
  WHERE f_table_name = 'XYGNIS' AND search_frame = 
  BuildCircleMbr(-70.250,    43.802, 0.1)) 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10
```

I cannot use it, however, since `ST_Distance` requiring compiling SpatiaLite with GEOS, which is in LGPL, which I cannot use. Is there a way I can do arithmetics to calculate distance and set that to a "variable" and then find the one with the minimal distance?

Comment: Maybe you want to move your question to http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good idea I will post it there, too. But isn't Stackoverflow for everything?

Comment: It is, but GIS is specific to that and you'll probably get more attention and better answers there.

Comment: If you want a distance, you'll have to calculate it. If you can't use GEOS, you can create your own extension or otherwise implement it (its basic cartesian math). However you should just use GEOS - no reason to not use LGPL code (I could understand GPL, but not LGPL).

Comment: Answer is on [GIS.Stackexchange][1]


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33617/1825